# installing Android SDK 2.3.3 (avoiding motodev login)

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-2.3

Edit: had to revise this whole question

Android SDK manager.  I check everything under 2.3.3  (API 10)
When I try to install it just goes through and says "Nothing was installed".

That's it lol, I can't install 2.3 at all.  What's wrong :(
This is what the log says

File not found: program files/android/android sdk/samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip (access is denied)

Then it skips everything
skipping 
skipping
Done. Nothing was installed.

Edit*
ANSWER.  I'm an idiot.  Right click, run as administrator.  rage@win7

Answer (score 0):

You can skip it'll will work fine. It asked me the same and I just clicked cancel.

There should be an option asking you to either login or cancel. So hit cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get the MOTODEV login at all if you aren't installing any Motorola addons. In the SDK Manager, do a "sort by repository" and make sure all the addons from Motorola are unchecked. At least that's how it is designed to work. If something else is occurring, please let me know. We tested the scenario on a lot of different configurations, especially Win7, but there could be something misconfigured.

Also, you can go into "Tools->Manage add-on sites" and remove any non-Google sites that you don't want to see.

[image]